# How do i insert a new column in Python dataset

Tags: python

I have a dataset that has a list of suppliers and manufacturers. I want to assign a unique number to each unique supplier and manufacturer. I am using Python and I am doing this to perform some Machine Learning predictions. This is what I have so far

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.read_csv('MasterData030617.csv')
X = df.dropna(axis=0)
numbers= np.unique(X['Supplier'], return_inverse=True)
numbers2 = np.unique(X['Logistics'], return_inverse=True)
```

Now this is where the problem happens. I want to take these new columns and add/insert into my original dataset. I thought the following would be the right way of doing it but I am getting errors:
X['New Supply'] = numbers
X['New Logistics'] = numbers2
where "New Supply' and 'New Logistics' are the names of the new columns I want to add to original data. When i run the last two commands i get the following error:
"

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-91f4a141e070> in <module>()
----> 1 X['New Supply'] = numbers
      2 X['New Logistics'] = numbers2

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   2417         else:
   2418             # set column
-> 2419             self._set_item(key, value)
   2420 
   2421     def _setitem_slice(self, key, value):

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _set_item(self, key, value)
   2483 
   2484         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 2485         value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
   2486         NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)
   2487 

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   2654 
   2655             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 2656             value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   2657             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   2658                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.pyc in _sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
   2798 
   2799     if len(data) != len(index):
-> 2800         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
   2801 
   2802     if isinstance(data, PeriodIndex):

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"
```

Can anyone please help on how I can accomplish my task and get rid of this error?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the length of `numbers` and `numbers2` does not match the shape of the `X` dataframe.

If you want to assign a unique number to each unique supplier and manufacturer, you can either create a mapping and use `pd.map()` or use sklearn's [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) (since you goal is to use Machine Learning here).

Comment: Hi, so once i use LabelEncoder and have a label/assigned number for each unique name, how do I insert the new columns (2 in this case) to the original dataset?